# How to get OSC to interact with Scheduling Routine in Supercollider

Tags: osc, supercollider

I am trying to use OSC messaging as a method of scheduling tasks/routines in Supercollider. Specifically I want a routine to wait until a message is received via OSC before resuming. So instead of (for example) 10.wait I want - something like : wait(OSC listener - message received, so continue). I have combed through the Supercollider documentation but have been unable to find anything that could be adapted to such a situation. Any suggestion as to a solution would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the documentation for the [`Condition`](http://doc.sccode.org/Classes/Condition.html) object. You can create a `Condition`, wait on it in one thread, and then resume that thread later on / from another thread, by using either `condition.unhang` or `condition.test_(true).signal`.

The code for your OSC message handler might look something like:

```
~stepCond = Condition();

Routine({
    "starting".postln;
    ~stepCond.wait;
    "continuing".postln;
}).play;

OSCfunc(\step, {
    ~stepCond.unhang();
}, '/step')
```